# Is there a way to make Prepros NOT minify the CSS output?

Tags: css, sass, minify, prepros

I want to process my SASS files, but don't want to minify the CSS.

I didn't find any config option to do that. Is there a way?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225364/how-to-change-output-options-in-prepros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to turn off the lib-sass option or just uncheck compress CSS option. 
[image]